# nginx, Limit all .php except index.php, allow POST

Tags: nginx, web.config

I'm trying to limit access to `.php` files through HTTP, allow only to index.php.

I should allow access to `.php` files only through `POST` and `require`.

I did the following:

```
    location ~ ^((?!index\.php).)*$ {   
        allow 127.0.0.1
        deny all;
    }
```

This blocks all files except `index.php`, however it blocks also `POST` queries..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locations apply to all requests types. Unfortunately the only way I can think to do this is using IF

```
location ~ ^((?!index\.php).)*$ {   
  if ($request_method = GET ) {
    allow 127.0.0.1
      deny all;
  }
}
```